# Are there functions in Android xamarin to backup or synchronize a sqlite database with Google Drive Api Rest?

Tags: xamarin.android, google-drive-api

I could see that the question came up often. By cons I have not yet found a solution to my problem. What I would like to do is allow my application to save the sqlite database containing user info on google drive. And also be able to make a daily backup of the data. With Xamarin android, I can't find much

Comment: Hi. Are you using sqlite-pcl package?

Comment: Do you want to send and store sqlite data on google drive ?

Comment: yes, i'm using sqlite-pcl-package. indeed, i want to send and store sqlite data on google drive. Can you help me, Please ?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to do it manually as of now there is no automated system for it.**

1. [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)
2. [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

You can use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for consuming RestApi of google drive and there is a great package [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert your class objects to JSON and vice-versa.

Comment: Right. i try it